# pip: bad interpreter: /../ no such file or directory

Tags: python

I can't use pip I get an error

```
pip: bad interpreter: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory
```

I try:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

```
python3 -m pip install whatever
```

```
brew install python

brew postinstall python
```

but nothing works.

Comment: can you tell the output of `where python3`

Comment: @sahasrara62 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

Comment: run this command -> `set python3=/usr/bin/python3` and try again `python3 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: added answer for the this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow python3 cmd is messed up in system by you. you need to reset it.

just run the command

```
set python3=/usr/bin/python3
```

now you can use `pip`